# WebAPI No action was found on the controller by passing parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

**HomeController.cs**

```
 class HomeController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetData(string name)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("username can not be empty");
            }
            return Ok("Test Done");
        }
    }
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {           
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "GetData",
              routeTemplate: "V2/{controller}/{name}",
              defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "GetData" }
              );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
```

**Getting error:**

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:4057/V2/Home/GetData/'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'Home'."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is simple.
The access modifier of your class is very restrictive

```
 class HomeController : ApiController
    {
```

The default access modifier is internal, meaning it is not publicly accessible.

Try to change the access modifier to `public` to expose the service publicly.

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
        {
```

I can replicate your issue using postman and my existing web API.

[image: My API Controller]

Error from my postman:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method name to `Get` (more about http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api).

Also setting the attribute routing might help if you do not want to change the method name (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

Comment: that [Routing] `Attribute` might be helpful. The `Name` of the method is not the problem here. Since he is using the `[HttpGet]` there won't be any issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Sherlock mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39741523/1163423), the API Controller must be public. However, consider using attribute routing over convention routing since its much less error prone:

**HomeController.cs:**

```
[RoutePrefix("V2/Home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{name}", Name = "GetData")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetData(string name)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("username can not be empty");
        }
        return Ok("Test Done");
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

Comment: As an additional also, routing annotation is only available in specific version of MVC, i think it was introduced in MVC 5

Comment: It was introduced in WebAPI 2.

Comment: @codran Yes which he is using due to the presents of `IHttpActionResult` in his code - right?

Comment: @MartinBrandl That does give it away, as does the user of `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes`. :)